# how to determine if two people are from the same location in active directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Assuming that active directory is set up correctly, I'm trying to find a way to determine whether or not two people are from the same location. The only way I was able to wrap my head around it is to find a way to determine whether or not their directory entry was located in the same OU. So currently, this is what I am spit-balling at the moment:

```
private bool ComparePeople()
{
    var user1Guid = "aaa";
    var user2Guid = "bbb";
    var expr = @"CN=.*?,";
    var user1OU = Regex.Replace(GetUserDN(user1Guid), expr, string.Empty);
    var user2OU = Regex.Replace(GetUserDN(user2Guid), expr, string.Empty);
    return user1OU == user2OU;
}
private string GetUserDN(string userGuid)
{
    using(var entry = new DirectoryEntry(string.format("LDAP://<GUID={0}>", userGuid)))
    {   
        using(var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
        {
            search.PropertiesToAdd.Add("distinguishedName");
            var result = search.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
            if(result != null && result.Properties["distinguishedName"].Count > 0)
            {
                return result.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
            }
            else return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this yet, but I feel like it would work. It basically finds the distinguished name of a user, give their Guid. Then it removes the CN from the DN, essentially finding the path to that user's directory entry/OU. However, it seems a bit convoluted. Does anyone have any comments or recommendations to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to find out whether two user accounts are located inside the same OU (organizational unit) - right?

What I would do is read the **parent** of both user accounts - if that parent matches, then they're in the same OU.

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a two users
UserPrincipal user1 = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Guid, user1Guid);
UserPrincipal user2 = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Guid, user2Guid);

if(user1 != null && user2 != null)
{
     DirectoryEntry dirEntry1 = user1.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
     DirectoryEntry dirEntry2 = user2.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

     // if both are OK, get the parents and compare their GUID
     if(dirEntry1 != null && dirEntry2 != null)
     {
         DirectoryEntry parent1 = dirEntry1.Parent;
         DirectoryEntry parent2 = dirEntry2.Parent;

         bool areInSameOU = (parent1.Guid == parent2.Guid);
     }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Aha, i was unaware of the Parent property. So here's a question. In the recent past, I have had bad luck with the AccountManagement namespace. It seemed like everything was getting processed noticeably slower. Is this normal, or do you think it was a fluke? Either way, it appears that all i really need to do is pull the directory entry and compare parents?